# How to link to new blank page in tbbuttongroup yii

Tags: yii

Given `tbbuttongroup` when user clicks the items I want to open a link to new blank page. I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup',
    array(
        'type' => 'primary',
        // '', 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
        'buttons' => array(
            array('label' => 'Action', 'url' => '#'),
            array(
                'items' => array(
                    array(
                            'label' => 'Cetak ke Pdf', 
                            'url' => array("Tbpinjaman/cetakpdf",id=>$_GET[id]),
                            'target'=>'_blank',
                        ),
                    array('label' => 'Export ke Excel', 'url' => 'Tbpinjaman/admin'),
                )
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'url'=> 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        'label'=>Yii::t('strings', 'stackoverflow'),
        'htmlOptions' => array('target'=>'_blank')
    )); 
?>
```

target on button widget must be put on htmloptions :

'htmlOptions' => array('target'=>'_blank')

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We welcome any correct answer, however we appreciate it more when an explanation regarding the fix is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use `linkOptions` for your anchor items

```
       'linkOptions' => array
       (
            'onclick' => "javascript:window.open('Tbpinjaman/cetakpdf/$_GET[id]','Your window name','width=500,height=700'); return false;"
       )
```

Your code will come like this.

```
        <?php
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array
        (
            'type' => 'primary',
            'buttons' => array
             (
                array('label' => 'Action', 'url' => '#', 'htmlOptions' => array('id' => 'buttonStateful'),),
                array
                (
                    'items' => array
                     (
                        array
                        (
                            'label' => 'Cetak ke Pdf',
                            'url' => '#', 
                            'linkOptions' => array
                             (
                                'onclick' => "javascript:window.open('Tbpinjaman/cetakpdf/$_GET[id]','Your window name','width=500,height=700'); return false;"
                             )
                        ),
                        array
                        (
                            'label' => 'Export ke Excel',
                            'url' => '#', 
                            'linkOptions' => array
                             (
                                'onclick' => "javascript:window.open('Tbpinjaman/admin','Your window name','width=500,height=700'); return false;"
                             )
                        )
                    )
                )
             )
        ));
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup',
    array(
        'type' => 'primary',
        // '', 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
        'buttons' => array(
            array('label' => 'Action', 'url' => '#'),
            array(
                'items' => array(
                    array(
                            'label' => 'Cetak ke Pdf', 
                            'url' => array("Tbpinjaman/cetakpdf",id=>$_GET[id]),
                            **'htmlOptions' => array('target'=>'_blank'),**
                    ),
                    array('label' => 'Export ke Excel', 'url' => 'Tbpinjaman/admin'),
                )
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.